# Mandar varios valores en un input text - array

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

Estoy haciendo un formulario en el que necesito que el cliente me ponga los productos que me va a enviar. Por lo cual he generado una programación en JavaScript, para que el usuario pueda ir añadiendo filas y así poder ponerme los articulos que me va a enviar uno por fila.

**Esta es la zona donde parto de una primera fila y luego puedo ir añadiendo más**

```
<div class="row" style="position:relative;" >
   <div class="col-6">
     <label class="labelMinis">Nombre del producto</label>
     <input type="text" name="name_producto[]" id="producto_1" value="" class="form-control inputMinis" placeholder="ejmp: Dragon hecho por mi">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="labelMinis">Estado del producto</label>
        <select class="form-control inputMinis" name="estado_producto[]" id="producto_1" style="overflow: hidden;">
          <option value="0">En matriz</option>
          <option value="1">Montado</option>
          <option value="2">Chusta</option>
          <option value="3">Conver</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="labelMinis">Und</label>
         <input type="number" class="form-control inputMinis" name="cantidad_producto[]" id="producto_1" min="1" value="1">
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

//Aquí añado más filas con una programación en JavaScript
<div id="tecnologias"></div>
<div id="AddMoreMedida_tecnologia" class="pull-right">
   <a href="#" id="AddTecnologia" class="btn btn-info pull-right btnSave margenBrn btnShow">Añadir fila</a><br><br>
</div>
```

Hasta aquí correcto, pero en este mismo formulario estoy usando dropzone que es para enviar imagenes con drag & drop, [aquí](https://docs.dropzone.dev/) dejo la documentación.

Al utilizar esto me he visto obligado a utilizar su forma de enviar las fotos para mandar el resto del formulario, entonces para poder enviar los demás campos además de las fotos mirando la documentación he visto esto (`this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData)`), pero no consigo que me llegue un array al controlador con las distintas filas.

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
        url: '{{ route('enviarMinis') }}',
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 5,
        maxFiles: 5,
        maxFilesize: 10,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictRemoveFile: "Eliminar",
        
        init: function() {
            dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.
    
            // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
            document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                dzClosure.processQueue();
            });
    
            //send all the form data along with the files:
            //Con esto puedo mandar el resto de datos del formulario, pero aunque le pongo name_producto[] solo recibo en el controlado el primer elemento.
            this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("productos", jQuery('input[name="name_producto[]"]').val());
                formData.append("postal", jQuery("#postal").val());
            });
        }
    }
```

---

He conseguido esto, pero me lo separa por comas en lugar de crear un array.

```
formData.append("productos", jQuery('input[name="name_producto[]"]').map(function (idx, elem) {
                    return $(elem).val();
                 }).get());
```

Comment: Que tal si conviertes el resultado separado por comas en `array` usando el método `split()`?

Comment: Hola @DjCrazy si lo pense, pero ya por cabezoneria queria mandarlo como un array desde ahí